# R reading annotation columns by read.ilmn of package limma

Tags: r, bioconductor

Package [limma](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) is one of the best - or even the best - package for reading microarray - and recently RNA-seq - experiment results and doing other process like normalization, fitting linear models, finding top differentially expressed genes, making plots and so on.

I have a minor problem in `read.ilmn()` function for reading illumina results: Suppose there are some annotation columns - i.e. ENTREZ_GENE_ID, REFSEQ_ID, and so on. These columns are needed to be read in addition to the expression columns - i.e. PROBE_ID, SYMBOL, AVG_Signal and Detection.Pval - for later analysis.

I have tried to pass the names of these columns as the `annotation` and `other.columns` arguments of `read.ilmn()` informing this command to read these columns also, resulting in failure of `read.ilmn()`. Finally I had to read these columns separately by a `read.table()` command and merging them manually with `read.ilmn()` results.

Is there any better way to perform the mission?

Comment: It would help to see an example of the code you are using, especially illustrating the meaning of 'resulting in failure'. The Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) has a no-subscription form and is closely followed by the limma package maintainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by manually reading the annotation columns and joining it to the list result of the `read.ilmn()`.